# Who are the rest of members at Elrond's Council?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In Peter Jackson's film *The Fellowship of the Ring*, when the Council of Elrond takes place it shows a total of 22 members:

[image]

We all know the names of the ones who were part of the Fellowship, but I want to know who are the rest of the people in the council. Who are the elves that came with Legolas? The men next to the dwarves? The three old men sitting next to Boromir? Or the two elves next to Aragorn?

Starting from left to right:

1. Frodo
2. Gandalf
3. Elf
4. Elf
5. Legolas
6. Elf
7. Old Man
8. Old Man
9. Dwalin
10. Gloin
11. Gimli
12. Nori
13. Old Man
14. Boromir
15. Old Man
16. Old Man
17. Elf
18. Elf
19. Aragorn
20. Elladan
21. Elrond
22. Elrohir

Comment: Is the question for the movie or the book?

Comment: Agreed, there is a large difference between the two

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Old Man 8 is really Bilbo.

Comment: According to the book, notable participants you haven't listed are (According to Lord of the Rings.wikia): Erestor - an elf and one of Elrond's advisors
Thranduil, King of the Wood-Elves of Mirkwood.
Glorfindel - a powerful Elf-lord of Rivendell
Galdor of the Havens, messenger of Círdan

Comment: @SSumner - Thranduil wsn't there. He sent his son Legolas to Rivendell to tell Elrond about Gollum escaping.

Comment: @DVK - That's what I thought, I just took that from the LOTR wikia page. Hence why it's a comment and not an answer. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 13):

From http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Council_of_Elrond:

> *The following people are known to have attended the Council:*
>   Elrond.
>   Gandalf.
>   Frodo Baggins.
>   Bilbo Baggins.
>   Glorfindel.
>   Erestor, and several unnamed advisors of Elrond's household.
>   Aragorn.
>   Boromir.
>   Glóin and his son Gimli.
>   Legolas.
>   Galdor of the Havens, a messenger of Círdan who just happened to be present at the time. His role in the Council was no larger than asking a couple of questions.

Also, for the 2001 LOTR movie:

> The only characters who speak are the protagonists who will later form the Company of the Ring. Unrelated characters (such as Bilbo, Erestor or Gloin) are absent or don't speak at all. **According to Decipher cards, some of the non-speaking participants are tradesmen from Dale and Lake-town. Figwit is also present.**

Comment: Samwise Gamgee was present but uninvited.

Comment: @LAK ...so were Meriadoc Brandybuck and Peregrin Took

Comment: @xDaizu Merry and Pippin weren't at the Council (though they were in Rivendell at the time).

Comment: @LAK True in the books, but I was referring to the movie

Comment: *Everyone* at the council just happened to be there at the time, having come to seek Elrond's advice for their own reasons. No one was specifically summoned for the purpose of holding a council. It was simply deemed providential that so many representatives of those that opposed (or at least were not allied with) Sauron were present at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

For the possible characters I went through 2 sets of trading card to find out about their info, here is the possible list:

**Dwarves**

- Farins, dwarven emissary
- Linnar, dwarven lord
- Grimir, dwarven emissary
- Thrarin, Dwarven Smith
- Sindri, dwarven lord
- Fror, Gimli's Kinsman
- Gloin
- Gimli

**Elves**

- Silinde, Elf of Mirkwood
- Calaglin, Elf of Lorien
- Galdor, Councilor From the West
- Golradir, Councilor of Imladris
- Saelbeth, Elven Councilor

**Men**

- Hugin, Emissary from Laketown
- Járnsmid, Merchant from Dale
- Erland, Advisor to Brand / Erland, Dale Counselor
- Ottar, Man of Laketown
- Jarnsmid, Barding Emissary
- Anborn, Skilled Huntsman

but the best idea might be to go through the film's credit to search for them.

Comment: Which trading cards are these?

Comment: @Valorum, I'm fairly sure they're Decipher's *The Lord of the Rings Trading Card Game* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_Trading_Card_Game).

Comment: Járnsmid *and* Jarnsmid? Someone got bored thinking up new names.

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost 9 years late with this answer, but as much as I know the elf who is sitting next to Aragorn is called Figwit. So the(18.). He's nonexistent in the books and his name was made up from "Frodo is great...Who is that?" He appears later in the trilogy when Arwen is leaving for the Grey Havens and he tries to stop her. He is played by Bret McKenzie who plays Lindir in The Hobbit movies but they are two separate elves.

Comment: Figwit is, of course, a ***fan-created name*** for this otherwise unnamed character; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figwit

Comment: It's okay to be nine years late as long as you're adding something new, but sadly, you aren't. The top-voted answer from January 2013 already mentions Figwit.

Comment: Is there any confirmation that they're separate characters? It would make more sense if they're both Lindir.