# How were all the men able to resist the ring when they saw it at the Council of Elrond?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

It was just sitting right there and they seemed OK with it; quite unlike the raging temptation the One Ring is made out to be (especially to the race of men).

They all stayed pretty chill. **What gives?**

Comment: Peer pressure, I reckon.

Comment: Shippey discusses this in *The Road To Middle Earth* and IIRC in *Author of the Century*. His thesis is that the Ring is not just *tempting* but also *addictive*.

Comment: I believe it "sitting right there" was a Peter Jackson invention, and not Tolkien.

Comment: @Scott, that is quite correct. Frodo had it on its chain and only brought it out when asked.

Comment: Why is it that you think that humans are especially susceptible to instant lust for power?

Comment: @tchrist *Elrond:* `Men? Men are weak. The Blood of Numenor is all but spent, its pride and dignity forgotten. It is because of Men the Ring survives. I was there, Gandalf. I was there three thousand years ago. I was there the day the strength of Men failed.`

Comment: @MatthewRead Elrond never said that: those are just ugly lies that Peter Jackson told.  Pure fanfic, and pure nonsense, too.

Comment: @tchrist I'm aware that's a movie line, but I disagree that it's "fanfic" or "nonsense" when the books clearly go into the fall, failure, and corruptability of Men.  Aragorn and Faramir are presented as exceptions.

Comment: @tchrist #notAllMen

Comment: Like @Richard says. The Ring, when present in polite company, has much the same properties as a single After Eight mint.

Comment: You have to remember that the ring isn't passive, it's actively trying to get home. If it makes anyone around it instantly turn crazy, then no one would think it'd be a good idea to send it along with Boromir. The ring wants people to trust it, to think they can use it, so it can more easily betray them later.

Comment: They were each waiting for someone else to make the first move.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The effect of the Ring on a person isn't instantaneous. Consider that it took Boromir four months (from the Council of Elrond in late October until the breaking of the Fellowship in late February) to be completely overwhelmed by the seduction of the Ring. And even then, he "falls over the brink" only for a relatively brief time, and quickly recovers and realizes that this is only a trick of the Ring, not a rational urge:

> For a while he was as still as if his own curse had struck him down; then suddenly he wept. He rose and passed his hand over his eyes, dashing away the tears. 'What have I said?' he cried. 'What have I done? Frodo, Frodo!' he called. 'Come back! A madness took me, but it has passed. Come back!'

(*Fellowship of the Ring*, Book II, Chapter 10, "The Breaking of the Fellowship")

Keep in mind as well that the Elves of Rivendell may actually have touched the Ring while Frodo was recovering in Rivendell. At any rate, they transferred the Ring from its original chain (by which, as we're told in "The Shadow of the Past", it hung inside his pants pocket) to a new chain around his neck.

With that in mind, it's reasonable to believe that "exposure" to the Ring for even a few days or weeks is not necessarily harmful to an individual.

Comment: Agreed. I think the issue is that the film needs to show the ring as *instantly* attractive in order for the later reveal (Boromir's betrayal) to make any sense.

Comment: @Richard I haven't seen the movies in a *long* time; is the stay at Rivendell much shorter in the movies?

Comment: The council itself is much shorter in the film.

Comment: The length of the stay (in the film) is ambiguous, but it seems like after Frodo recovers, the Council and the departure of the Fellowship takes a day or two.

Comment: The counterexample to the ring taking a long time is Smeagol nearly immediately after his friend finds the ring.

Comment: Boromir and the Elves were stronger people (physically, mentally, and morally) than Smeagol was, though. Even aside from natural strength, Smeagol had developed a pretty selfish perspective before he ever saw the Ring, or it wouldn't have gotten hold of him so quickly. Gandalf says that a person's intentions do have a bearing on how the Ring impacts them--take Bilbo, who picked it up innocently, used it for good or neutral purposes, and thus took sixty years to begin feeling the Ring's effects.

Comment: Another example of the ring not having negative effects is Sam. As far as I could tell, he was not permanently effected after briefly carrying it, and was *mostly* immune to temptation.

Comment: I believe I recall Gandalf commenting that part of the reason Frodo Sam and Bilbo did well, and why he trusted them with it, was because they were hobbits

Comment: @MattGutting makes sense. But! Gandalf refuses to touch the ring at Frodo's house even just to check is the One.

Comment: @algiogia: Gandalf's motives are not explained, but I'm pretty sure the idea that him (a Maiar) touching the ring might expose him (and the ring) to Sauron immediately might have played into that. He didn't even want to touch the Palantir directly for just that reason...

Comment: @algiogia Gandalf also admitted that, were he to take the ring and become corrupted by it, knowingly or unknowingly, he would become a terribly powerful force for evil. Speculation: Probably as powerful and dangerous as the Witch King of Angmar (as Gandalf the Grey. As Gandalf the White, who knows).

Comment: @algiogia Movies only. In the book, *Gandalf* takes and handles the ring after removing it from the fire. It makes much more sense as well; if if his theory was wrong, he'd be risking Frodo's burns in the movie version, but his own in the book one.

Comment: @Angew my bad. You are right. That's why I watched only the first movie.

Comment: If the effect isn't instantaneous, how come Isildur was unable to destroy the ring when he went to Mount Doom? (I'm assuming Isildur went to destroy the ring as soon as he acquired it, as shown in the movie. I don't remember the timeline of the book.)

Comment: @Shahzeb in the book he didn't try; he took it as weregild (revenge payment) for the deaths of his father and brother. The elves tried to convince him not to, but he wouldn't listen.

Comment: I would submit that Smeagol probably wasn't a saint to begin with, and it didn't take much for the Ring to corrupt him.

Comment: There's an argument that Galadriel's testing of Boromir is what pushed him over the edge.

Answer (score 27):

At the Council of Elrond, Boromir gives us a pretty strong indication that the power of the ring isn't *instantaneously* corrupting. In fact, to begin with they even dispute that it's Isildur's ring at all, requiring evidence from both Elrond himself and Gandalf before they accept that they need to do anything about it;

> Isildur's Bane is found, you say,' said Boromir. **I have seen a
>   bright ring in the Halfling's hand; but Isildur perished ere this age
>   of the world began, they say. How do the Wise know that this ring is
>   his?** And how has it passed down the years, until it is brought hither
>   by so strange a messenger?'. <sub><sup>FotR:The Council of Elrond</sup></sub>

As @MattGuring his pointed out, it then takes months for him to get to the point that he's willing to break his oaths as a loyal warrior of Gondor.

Comment: Good find on the quote.

Comment: Good point. The ring didn't appear or act special. In most cases, it seems the "least" of all magic rings.

Comment: Boromir didn't make an oath to defend him, he was just going with them on the way back to Minas Tirith, wasn't he?

Comment: @ZenLogic: Indeed Elrond made a point of *not* oath-binding the Fellowship.

Comment: Oaths were personally made by Gimli, Legolas, and Aragorn. Boromir never made one, though.

Comment: Edit made. He's clearly gone off the rails either way.

Comment: @Richard indeed. The man clearly punched his ticket for The Crazy Train.

Answer (score 19):

There were only two Men at the Council of Elrond - Aragorn and Boromir.

The full tally of attendees is given at the start of the chapter and may be quoted here:

> He then pointed out and named those whom Frodo had not met before. There was a younger dwarf at **Glóin**'s side: his son **Gimli**. Beside **Glorfindel** there were several **other counsellors of Elrond's household**, of whom **Erestor** was the chief; and with him was **Galdor**, an Elf from the Grey Havens who had come on an errand from Círdan the Shipwright. There was also a strange Elf clad in green and brown, **Legolas**, a messenger from his father, Thranduil, the King of the Elves of Northern Mirkwood. And seated a little apart was **a tall man with a fair and noble face**, dark-haired and grey-eyed, proud and stern of glance.

There were therefore no other Men to be tempted.

Comment: Does "a tall man with a fair and noble face" reference Aragorn? I'd assume that Frodo already met and knew him as Strider, but I guess if he had his hood up and the effects of the wild upon him, he'd be unrecognizable.

Comment: @TylerH that's Boromir; Aragorn is referenced in a previous paragraph.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For starters, we aren't privy to the thoughts and inner dialogues of the men around the table, so it's not fair to assume they aren't tempted. For all we know, several of them could be thinking about how valuable of an asset the ring would be to their prospective kingdoms/represented groups. Boromir, in fact, says as much... with only Aragorn showing any disagreement.

Also, with regards to the movie version, the un-named older men sitting near Boromir [are said to be tradesmen from Dale](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28978/20557) (Laketown) and other settlements. Many of them may not know of the ring or its power, beyond what is whispered in legend. Even so, Sméagol seems to be the only individual in the entire epic who is affected by the ring instantly. All others appear to succumb to its power gradually. Others must be exposed over time.

On a side note, since reading your question I now have this insane image from the movie of one of the old guys snatching the ring off the tree trunk and running off shouting "Mine!".

Answer (score 3):

1.) Temptation over time

The ring works over time.  For example, as given in another answer Boromir changes only after a significant period of time.  The same can be said for Smeagol who slowly transforms into Gollum over a VERY long period of time.  Bilbo while tempted by the power of the ring doesn't suffer any negative effects for months and is able to hold the ring for years.

2.) Rivendell

...is not a normal place.  This is one of the last great strongholds.  It may look like a peaceful village but it is guarded by Elrond's magic and those of his closest councilors and has managed to keep out all sorts of unsavory sorts for several hundred years.  It is a magic fortress and we would expect that the enchantments that protect it also work to abate the effects of the ring.

Answer (score 0):

Those present at the Council of Elrond were leadership reps for their respective branches of people. They were all agents for good, and all were there because of Sauron's attempts to get in their business. Elrond is speaking about how they all came together with no invitation:

> You will learn that your trouble is but part of the trouble of all the
>   western world. The Ring! What shall we do with the Ring, the least of
>   rings, the trifle that Sauron fancies?
>
> That is the doom that we must deem. That is the purpose for which you
>   are called hither. Called, I say. Though I have not called you to me,
>   strangers from distant lands. You have come and are here met, in this
>   very nick of time, by chance as it may seem. Yet it is not so. Believe
>   rather that it is so ordered that we, who sit here, and none others,
>   must now find counsel for the peril of the world.

These people, excepting maybe Boromir and his huge ego thinking he could master anything (but already at the Council he is being mastered by the One's influence) knew this to be something abhorrently evil. The cause of so much of each of their people's problems