# Who were all the attendees at the Council of Elrond?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Besides the actual fellowship and Elrond, who else attended the meeting in Rivendell? In the movie, it looks like there are around 20 or so attendees. Who were they? How closely does this match the book?

Comment: http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Council_of_Elrond

Comment: http://www.amagpiesnest.com/a/p_characters-actors/council/council_elrond.htm

Comment: There you go. Copy and paste the lists on the two sites above and win yourself 10 upvotes for the trouble.

Comment: So the LOTR wiki is from the book? And the amagpiesnest is from the movie? I noticed the wiki has Gloin as part of the council whereas amagpie says Gloin was not part of the council (but was in rivendell at the time). While amagpie has FIGWIT at the council but he's not mentioned on the wiki list.

Comment: @Valorum - Forgot to tag you on my previous comment.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28978/who-are-the-rest-of-members-at-elronds-council

Comment: @iMerchant - The wiki is usually from the book. The film was actually pretty faithful (all things considered) and rarely *adds* much to the canon